# Java, Finding smallest number in an array

Tags: java, while-loop

Ths is a question from a past paper. I have been asked to create a static method `arrayMin` to find the smallest value in the array `arr`.

I have to use a while loop and on each iteration, the variable `min` will return the smallest number from the first `i` elements.

Is there a way to do this without calling another method/for loop and strictly using the while loop, as the question is only worth 4%(including writing loop invariants and javadoc). Not sure if I am overcomplicating the problem.

```
public class Revision {

public static int arr[] = new int[] { 5, 8, 4, 3, 6, 2 };
public static int min = 1;

public static int arrayMin() {

    int i = 0;

    if (arr == null) {
        return 0;

    } else {
        while (i < arr.length) {
            // some function/method call to find smallest number of arr[i]
            i++;
            return min;
        }
    }
    return min;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(arrayMin());
}
```

`}`

Comment: In your code you will always return `1` if `arr != null` and otherwise `0` because of your `return min` statement in the `while` loop.

Comment: I think it is a nice optimization to return the minimum value in the range that the values in the range can take for each element in the array. Note that in Java, 0 may not be the minimum, integers may have negative values.

Comment: A value of `null` normally does not mean the same as an array of 0 elements. You are better off checking against null and throwing a `NullPointerException` or `IllegalArgumentException` if you encounter null for the array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. The array shouldn't be static, you should pass it as a *parameter* to the `arrayMin` method;
2. `min` should be a local `arrayMin` variable, not static;
3. `min` should be initialized to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If you initialize it with `1`, and `2` happens to be the min value of the array, you'll never return it;
4. You can't return multiple times from a method. As soon as you do `return min`, the method ends. There's probably some confusion over the *the variable min will return the smallest number from the first i elements* phrase. It probably means that in each *iteration*, the variable `min` will *have* (not return) the smallest number from the first `i` elements.

Here's a refactor:

```
public static int arrayMin(int[] arr) {
    int i = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (arr == null) {
        return 0; // What if 0 is the minimum value? What do you want to do in this case?
    } else {
        while (i < arr.length) {
            if (arr[i] < min) {
              min = arr[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the additional explanations, but please don't return full code for programming assignments.

Answer (score 6):

You need to have a variable outside of the loop called `min`. You will use the loop to find the minimum of the array, and return `min` when the loop is complete.

```
} else {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while(i < arr.length) {
        // is arr[i] < min? If so, it's the new minimum
        i++;
    }

    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

multiple ways to do it, but here is one.
public static int arrayMin(int[] arr) {

```
            boolean isFirstElement = true;

            int smallestNumber= 0;

            int index = 0;

            while(index < arr.length) {

                int temp= arr[index];

                 index++;

                if (isFirstElement) {

                    smallestNumber = temp;

                    isFirstElement = false;

                } else if (smallestNumber > temp) {

                    smallestNumber = temp;
                }
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a index variable to keep in track of the number of positive hits and if the corresponding numbers index value is one lesser the array size, that number is the smallest

```
class testtt{
    static int small=0;
    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};      
        int i,index=0;      
        for(int q:arr)
        {                   
            for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {               
                if(q<arr[i])
                {
                    small=q;
                    index++;
                }
            }
            if(index==arr.length-1)
                System.out.println(small);  
        }   

    }
}
```